# How to check for exactly two elements in a Prolog list

Tags: list, prolog

```
% The structure of a musical group takes the form
% group(Groupname, Director, Players).
% Players is a (possibly empty) list of musician structures,
% but excludes the musician structure for the Director.
% The Director is also a musician in the group.
% musician structures take the form
% musician(Initials,Surname,
% cv(Years_as_professional,Previous_orchestra,Instrument)).

group(classicalstars,
      musician(w,mozart,cv(10,vienna_phil,piano)),
      [musician(j,haydn,cv(32,vienna_phil,cello)), musician(j,bach,cv(40,dresden_chamber,viola))]).
group(romantics,
      musician(l,beethoven,cv(32,vienna_phil,piano)),
      [musician(f,liszt,cv(10,vienna_phil,violin))]).
group(nordicsounds,
      musician(e,grieg,cv(50,bergen_phil,piano)),
      [ ]).
group(impressions,
      musician(g,faure,cv(40,paris_chamber,violin)),
      [musician(c,saint-saens,cv(51,paris_chamber,violin)), musician(m,ravel,cv(10,paris_chamber,piano)), musician(o,messiaen,cv(5,paris_chamber,violin))]).

director(X):- group(_,X,_).

musicians(X):- group(_,_,Musicians),
              member(X,Musicians).

exists(X):- director(X);
            musicians(X).
```

So I am trying to return the Initial and Surname of the director of the group that has exactly two non-director musicians that play the violin.
So far I have this

```
 hasTwoViolinists(Initial,Surname):- group(_,musician(Initial,Surname,_),[musician(_,_,cv(_,_,violin)),musician(_,_,cv(_,_,violin))]).
```

Which will only return a group that only has two violinists, which isn't quite what I am looking for
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I take it that the impressions group is the correct group and that the answer is (g,faure). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is the answer I would be looking for in this case

Comment: Do you want a complete solution or just hints? I am asking because if you are trying to learn and see a complete solution it might not help you as much. Your choice.

Comment: A hint to start would be nice

Comment: I have all but the last rule working. I am pretty sure it will work once I get the bugs out. So I will give you the first hint in the answer and then and more later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I did was to understand the structure of your data and noticed that finding a list of musicians that had exactly two violinist would be the inner most rule so I started on that.

Here is a rule to find exactly two items in a list. It needs to be enhanced to work on the musicians list for the violinist.

```erlang
find(C,_,C,[]).  % True when Count exactly equals Total and list is empty.

% When the head of the list is the item increment the count and do the next item.
find(Total,Item,Count,[H|T]) :-
      Item = H,
      Count1 is Count + 1,
      find(Total,Item,Count1,T).

% When the head of the list is not the item do the next item.
find(Total,Item,Count,[H|T]) :-
      Item \= H,
      find(Total,Item,Count,T).

% find(2,a,0,[a,b,a,c]).
% true .
%
% find(2,a,0,[a,a,a,c]).
% false.
```

Note: The hints are [spoilers](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) and can be seen by moving your mouse over them.
If the hint has a code solution it is below all of the hints and also as a spoiler so you have to move the mouse to see them.

Hint 1:

> [Predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) are your friend with Logic Programming.

Hint 2:

> Create a Predicate that returns true when a musician is a violinist, and false when a musician is not a violinist.
>
>  is_violinist(musician(o, messiaen, cv(5, paris_chamber, violin))).
>  true.
>
>  is_violinist(musician(m, ravel, cv(10, paris_chamber, piano))).
>  false.

Hint 3:

> `find` used two predicates.
>
>  Item = H  and
>  Item \= H
>
>  what happens when they are replaced with `is_violinist`
>
>  For reference:
>  [=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2)
>  [\=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%3D/2)
>  [\+](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1) is the same as not.

Hint 4:

> Now that you can find the musicians with the two violinist how can you use that to find the group?

Hint 5:

> Now that you can find the group with the two violinist how can you use that to find the directors initial and surname?

Code for hints. Sorry about the formatting, [limits of markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/181143).

2.

> is_violinist(musician(_,_,cv(_,_,violin))).

3.

> % True when Count exactly equals Total and list is empty.
>  find_v(C,C,[]).
>
>  % When is_violinist is true for the head of the list increment the count and do the next item.
>  find_v(Total,Count,[H|T]) :-
>        is_violinist(H),
>        Count1 is Count + 1,
>        find_v(Total,Count1,T).
>
>  % When is_violinist is not true for the head of the list do the next item.
>  find_v(Total,Count,[H|T]) :-
>        \+ is_violinist(H),
>        find_v(Total,Count,T).

4.

> find_group(Group) :-
>        group(Group,_,Musicians),
>        find_v(2,0,Musicians).

5.

> find_director(Initial,Surname) :-
>        group(_,musician(Initial,Surname,_),Musicians),
>        find_v(2,0,Musicians).

Comment: You said there was a bug, any chance it is because "Count1 is Count + 1" should be "Count is Count + 1,"

Comment: I have the rules giving the correct answer now in my code, AFAIK there is no bug with `find`, but will now run more test cases on my side.

Comment: No it should not be `Count is Count + 1` because you need to use a different variable to pass the incremented count to the next rule, e.g. `Count1`. In Prolog variables are not like in imperative code, you can not keep changing their value. See: [Variables and how they are set and used in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026201/1243762)

Comment: Ah okay, yeah I see how your find code is working now.  I will report back if I can't figure out how to use it with finding violins lol

Comment: \+ is_violinist(H)
Does this mean if its false?

Comment: See: [SWI-Prolog not/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1) Read as: `H is not a violinist`. And since `H` is a musician, `\+ is_violinist(H)` can be read as: `a musician that is not a violinist`

Comment: Thank you so much, its so simple in hindsight XD

Comment: @BobbyBorn2L8 Don't thank me, thank the people who invented Prolog and made the free versions of Prolog available. That is what made it so simple. In working with logic and functional programming I find that starting with the inner most routines first and working back out is often the best approach.

Comment: You can also enhance the code by modifying `find` to  accept `is_violinist` as a argument, e.g. `find(Total,Predicate,Count,[H|T])` and using `call` e.g. `call(Predicate,H),`

Comment: Another question is it necessary to have find_v(C,C,[]).?

Comment: Never mind I removed it and see its purpose is to return something when it reaches the end of the list

Comment: It is also important that it is the first of the three `find` rules. Move to the second or third position and see what happens. It is also important to note that find is a predicate it returns only true or false, not a list or an item, thus a predicate.

Comment: `find_v(C,C,[]).` is the only rule of the three `find` rules that returns true. With a predicate once you know it is true you can stop searching but if you get false you have to continue searching.