# How to create an arbitary variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

A newbie query

given N a number  , I would like to create a variable XN in prolog .
N=3,createvar(N,test),write(X3).
must produce test as the answer .

Is this possible

Rephrasing the Q

I need some thing similar to length(S,N). which creates a N anoymous variables .

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or impossible, but [Prolog variables are not the same as other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026201) and may not make it easy to bind `X3` inside `createvar()` which is also usable outside. (Before you edited your question it suggests a list of values which sum `<K`, and mapping `P(X, Y)` over the list using `maplist` or `findall` or `foreach`; creating variables with numbers in their names is often something programming beginners reach for, not knowing about better options, and is usually more difficult to work with).

Comment: I removed the origial Q because I thought I had whittled the q down to this issue . let me rephrase the q again

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new *variable name* to your clause. When reading left-to-right, a new variable name indicates a "fresh variable" that is "as yet unbound" / "so far uninstantiated".

No need to declare a variable explicity. They are just names for places selected from an infinite (or at least RAM-sized) sea of places. For example

```
foo(X) :- bar(X,Y),baz(Y,X).
                ^
                |
                You needed a new variable, you now have it.
```

A "fresh variable" named `Y` has been added to the set of variables used in this clause by naming it in the call to `bar(X,Y)`.

In particular, the variable name `_` can be used to name fresh variables without inventing new names. Any variable named `_` is different from all other variables

```
X=[_,_,_,_,_].
```

You created 5 fresh variables by naming them `_`. Note that `X` is initially also a fresh variable but then gets unified with the (tip of) the 5-element list.

When printing, SWI Prolog gives uninstantiated variables unique names derived from the position in some internal datastructure:

```
?- X=[_,_,_,_,_].
X = [_6480,_6486,_6492,_6498,_6504].
```

Comment: Thanks This is same as given before. Does not answer the requirement explicitly

Comment: I think OP is asking about "variable variables" [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @SunilChandras @TessallatingHeckler In that case, there is only [`nb_setval/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setval/2) and [`b_setval/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=b_setval/2) and friends which **set** thread-local global variables. Use only in special cases!